# Посмотреть изображение на другом диске

Tags: html, php

Предположим:

```
Есть веб-сервер (c:/webserver)
Сам сайт (c:/webserver/site)
Есть изображение (d:/img/img.jpg)
```

Как отобразить это изображение средствами html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[File (схема URI)](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_URI)). Это, конечно, если совсем заняться больше нечем :)

Comment: Я б даже так сказал: само понятие "логический диск" никакого отношения к веб-серверу не имеет. Если, конечно, вы не настолько богаты, чтобы использовать решения от Microsoft.

Comment: Лично для меня проще, **качественней, надёжней и логичней** вести разработку в той среде, которая будет крутиться на продакшне. Поэтому я работаю под дебианом, не компостирую мозги ни себе, ни людям, не разгребаю тонны проблем несовместимости, не занимаюсь ветвлением кода на платформенно-зависимые куски даже в сишностях, и вообще, живу весело и счастливо. Чего и всем желаю :)

Нет, конечно, если ваша цель - разрабатывать приложения для майкрософтовских платформ, то это уже совсем другой разговор...

Comment: @klopp +1 тем более что виртуалбокс работает прекрасно, а память стоит копейки. (я правда предпочитаю винду в виртуалке раз в пол года, а на десктопе линукс, тож debian)

Comment: все не так страшно, я просто хочу свой велосипед с блэк джеком и шл***ми..=)
сначала это был просто скрипт, который делал кое-какие махинации с файлами, потом у него появился userfriendly интерфейc, а теперь он должен контролировать всё)

Comment: да не открыть мне надо, а в теге <img> показать превьюшку (изображение)

Comment: <img src="file:///home/klopp/xxx/Pictures/test.jpg" />

Вполне работает, и в локальном файле, и на веб-сервере. Что с логическими дисками - не знаю, лень эмулятор виндов запускать. Но не вижу никаких препятствий.

Comment: Сам себе противоречишь... это если ты локально запустишь файлик браузером какой-нибудь test.html с твоим img src="file:///" то конечно все будет работать, а ты попробуй запустить под из под веб сервера этот же файлик и желательно хромом =)

Comment: Значит, текущая политика безопасности не позволяет ссылаться так на файлы за пределами DocumentRoot. В любом случае, IMHO, проблема выеденного яйца не стоит.

Comment: откорректируй свой ответ, и я сделаю его правильным.
да, и спасибо за наводки, узнал много полезного)